# Azure Discrete VMs vs Virtual Desktop

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to setup a collection of Azure workstation VMs for a small organisation (3 staff and increasing).

My prior experience with Azure is focused on web servers.  I'm familiar and comfortable with the resources required for discrete VMs (VM, managed disk, network interface, public IP, DNS).

On the face of it, Azure Virtual Desktop looks like a potentially attractive option for scalability.  But I've just followed the Getting Started process, and I have ended up with around 25 new resources spread across three new resource groups.

It is not clear what each of them do or what each of them cost.  I am experiencing difficulties with trying to connect with the test user created as part of this process.

I understand that AVD is probably targeted at large organisations where this complexity may be warranted and navigable.

But with limited time to pursue this, I'm suspecting that the best option for constructing this small network may be to stay with the resources that I am familiar with.

Would appreciate feedback on the following:

1. It seems that discrete VMs can only be provisioned with a flavor of Windows Server, and desktop versions of Windows (ie, 10, 11) are only available via AVD.  Is there any downside to using Windows Server (compared to a desktop version) as the platform for a workstation?  The workload apps here are primarily development-focused: Office, Visual Studio, SSMS etc.
2. A copy of Office will be needed on each VM.  AVD has a bundled option for this, but I believe it can also be provisioned separately per VM via the Microsoft Account/Office 365 pathway.  Any licensing pitfalls there that I should be aware of?
3. If each staff member is to be allocated their own separate VM, we would want them to call that VM up and shut it down as needed, to avoid wasted compute expense for the majority of the daily cycle.  But without granting them access to the Azure portal account.   Is there a mechanism than can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but we do have multiple advantages and disadvantages.

It depends on operating system of the server but it is not that good idea.

**Performance Degradation** - Server should works as SERVICE PROVIDER and use it as workstation can consume its resources and cause degradation of its performance.

In some of the Windows server OS case it may be a good idea because of Windows Workstation OS versions supports only a limited number of processors (less then server version).

One is needed to disable IE enhanced security and few other available in the below link

Add windows features once the OS is installed etc.

Reference: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-Windows-Server-as-I-would-use-Windows-Desktop-i-e-Win-10-7-8

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_use_a_server_as_a_workstation

**Options:** Enable Hyper V on server and add multiple Workstation.

https://support.auvik.com/hc/en-us/articles/212801986-How-to-enable-Microsoft-Hyper-V-on-Windows-Servers-and-Workstations

**A copy of Office will be needed on each VM. AVD has a bundled option for this, but I believe it can also be provisioned separately per VM via the Microsoft Account/Office 365 pathway. Any licensing pitfalls there that I should be aware of?**

Office version with license can be installed manually and via application packaging. There will not be any challenges.

**If each staff member is to be allocated their own separate VM, we would want them to call that VM up and shut it down as needed, to avoid wasted compute expense for the majority of the daily cycle. But without granting them access to the Azure portal account. Is there a mechanism than can help with this?**

Automation is available to stop vm if not running in azure

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management-config